# File not found when trying to use etag

Tags: terraform

I am trying to use `etag` when i update my bucket S3, but i get this error:

```
Error: Error in function call
   on config.tf line 48, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "bucket_app":
   48:   etag = filemd5("${path.module}/${var.env}/app-config.json")
     |----------------
     | path.module is "."
     | var.env is "develop"
 Call to function "filemd5" failed: no file exists at develop/app-config.json.
```

However, this works fine:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "bucket_app" {
  bucket = "${var.app}-${var.env}-app-assets"
  key    = "config.json"
  source = "${path.module}/${var.env}/app-config.json"

  // etag = filemd5("${path.module}/${var.env}/app-config.json")

  depends_on = [
    local_file.app_config_json
  ]
}
```

I am genereting the file this way:

```
resource "local_file" "app_config_json" {
  content  = local.app_config_json
  filename = "${path.module}/${var.env}/app-config.json"
}
```

I really don't get what i am doing wrong...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All functions in Terraform run during the initial configuration processing, not during the graph walk. For all of the functions that read files on disk, that means that the files must be present on disk prior to running Terraform as part of the configuration itself -- usually, checked in to version control -- rather than being generated dynamically during the Terraform operation.

The documentation for [`file`], which [`filemd5`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/filemd5.html) builds on, has the following to say about it:

> This function can be used only with files that already exist on disk at the beginning of a Terraform run. Functions do not participate in the dependency graph, so this function cannot be used with files that are generated dynamically during a Terraform operation. We do not recommend using dynamic local files in Terraform configurations, but in rare situations where this is necessary you can use [the `local_file` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/local/d/file.html) to read files while respecting resource dependencies.

As the documentation there suggests, the `local_file` data source provides a way to read a file into memory as a resource during the graph walk, although its result would still need to be passed to [`md5`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/md5.html) to get the result you needed here.

Because you're creating the file with a `local_file` resource anyway, you can skip the need for the additional `data` resource and derive the MD5 hash directly from your `local_file.app_config_json` resource:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "bucket_app" {
  bucket = "${var.app}-${var.env}-app-assets"
  key    = "config.json"
  source = local_file.app_config_json.filename
  etag   = md5(local_file.app_config_json.content)
}
```

Note that we don't need to use `depends_on` if we derive the configuration from attributes of the `local_file.app_config_json` resource, because Terraform can therefore already see that the dependency relationship exists.

Comment: Thanks, helped me to fix an error with azurerm_storage_blob where content_md5(filemd5()) does not work on a zip file.

Note that it should be data.local_file.app_config_json.content

Answer (score 9):

If you happen to arrive here and are using an `archive_file` Data Source, there is an exported attribute called `output_md5`.  This seems to provide the same results that you would get from `filemd5(data.archive_file.app_config_json.output_path)`.

Here is a full example:

```
data archive_file config {
  type        = "zip"
  output_path = "${path.module}/config.zip"
  source {
    filename = "config/template-configuration.json"
    content  = "some content"
  }
}

resource aws_s3_bucket_object config{
  bucket       = aws_s3_bucket.stacks.bucket
  key          = "config.zip"
  content_type = "application/zip"
  source       = data.archive_file.config.output_path
  etag         = data.archive_file.config.output_md5
}
```